# Eigenvalues of the sum of two matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues

I know that given two matrices $A$ and $B$, estimating the eigenvalues of $A + B = C$ as a function of the eigenvalues of $A$ and of the eigenvalues of $B$ is generally a non-easy problem. I was wondering if the solution is known in the case where $A$ is *symmetric* and $B$ is *diagonal*. Thanks!

Comment: Read Fulton's survey, http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9908012

Comment: Assuming that by symmetric you mean real-symmetric, then this case would seem to be at least as hard as the case where A and B are Hermitian (since once can always conjugate A and B by a common matrix which diagonalizes B)

Comment: One of the works for which Terry Tao was given a Fields medal is precisely solving this problem. More precisely, he (with collaborator Knutson), proved Alfred Horn's conjecture. Well documented in Fulton's paper mentionned above.

Comment: People mostly know the eigenvalue problem for Hermitian matrices. However, the answer in the symmetric case is given by exactly the same inequalities (Klyachko's inequalities in non-recursive form and Horn's inequalities in the recursive form), see Fulton's survey article.  